# How to get around the Coverage Condition for Functional Dependencies without using -XUndecidableInstances

Tags: haskell, ghc, functional-dependencies, type-families

Wen using functional dependencies, I frequently hit the *Coverage Condition*.  It is possible to lift it with `UndecidableInstances`, but I usually try to stay away from that extension.

Here is a somewhat contrived example, that works without `UndecidableInstances`:

```
{-# Language MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances #-}

data Result = Result String
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data Arguments a b = Arguments a b

class Applyable a b | a -> b where
  apply :: a -> b -> Result

instance Applyable (Arguments a b) (a -> b -> Result) where
  (Arguments a b) `apply` f = f a b
```

When I make the result type more generic, the Coverage Condition fails (hence requiring `UndecidableInstances`):

```
{-# Language MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

data Result a = Result a
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data Arguments a b = Arguments a b

class Applyable a b c | a -> b c where
  apply :: a -> b -> Result c

instance Applyable (Arguments a b) (a -> b -> Result c) c where
  (Arguments a b) `apply` f = f a b
```

I thought that because `b` and `c` are both determined by `a`, the more generic code should not cause any problems, so my questions:

1. Are there any possible issues with using `UndecidableInstances` here
2. Can I model the above scenario without relying on `UndecidableInstances` (maybe with type families?)

Comment: There's no big reason to stay away from `UndecidableInstances`.  The worst that can happen is that the type checker starts looping (and tells you about it, I think).  You can make the coverage condition more and more clever, but it will never do everything you could want since that's undecidable.

Comment: how is c determined by a here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no big reason to stay away from `UndecidableInstances`. The worst that can happen is that the type checker starts looping (and tells you about it, I think). You can make the coverage condition more and more clever, but it will never do everything you could want since that's undecidable.