# Coverage condition fails for one of its dependencies

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write functions that use monad transformers but are agnostic with respect to the exact structure of my monadic type. I don't fully understand what I'm doing, though--trying to follow advice I got on #haskell. The idea is I want to write a function like

```
doSomething :: (MonadRandom m, MonadError MyError m ) => Arg -> m Result
```

(where m is a stack of monad transformers that add random generator state and error handling)

I started out writing some state:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

import System.Random
import Control.Monad.Error
import Control.Monad.State

{-
-- I want to make a class of monads which contain random generator state.
class Monad m => RandMonad m where
  putGen :: StdGen -> m ()
  getGen :: m StdGen
-}

-- the following creates a monadic type BT
data BTState = BTState
 { bGoalN :: Int
 , bRandState :: StdGen }
newtype BT m a = BT { runBT :: StateT BTState m a }

-- what the following does is say that if e and m can be used the 
-- way a monad error can be used, then so can e and (BT m)
instance MonadError e m => MonadError e (BT m) where
   throwError x = BT (throwError x)
   -- edit: I added the following definition but I'm still getting the same error
   -- In fact I tried every conceivable definition of catchError and still get the
   -- same error about the coverage condition
   catchError (BT x) y = BT (catchError y)
```

When I run this I'm getting "illegal instance declaration for 'MonadError e (BT m)' (the coverage condition fails for one of its dependencies)"

I'm a haskell newbie so I don't know what this means.

Comment: edited to reflect attempt to define `catchError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coverage condition has nothing to do with how you implement the instance. In the definition of `MonadError`

```
class (Monad m) => MonadError e m | m -> e where
```

the functional dependency says that for a given instance `m` we must be able to uniquely determine `e`.

The problem is that in the definition like yours

```
instance MonadError e m => MonadError e (BT m) where
```

GHC isn't able to determine that from `BT m` we can determine `m` and from `m` (using the instance `MonadError e m`) we can determine `e`. So in order to define your instance, you need to enable `UndecidableInstances`. See also [How to get around the Coverage Condition for Functional Dependencies without using -XUndecidableInstances](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9076179/1333025). Note that all `MonadError` instances are defined like this, see [the source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.1.3.1/docs/src/Control-Monad-Error-Class.html#MonadError).

In your case, I'd suggest to use existing [MonadRandom](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.13/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Class.html#t:MonadRandom) and its corresponding monad transformer [RandT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.13/docs/Control-Monad-Random.html#t:RandT). You'll have to define a `MonadError` instance for `RandT` yourself though.